# Growing hibiscus in an 8a zone

Tags: houseplants, hibiscus

I'd like to grow a hibiscus plant and wonder if that's even possible during the winter in Oregon. I assume I'll need to keep it indoors to keep it warm, but I have a very small space with limited sunlight. What are some growing options I could try to get a hibiscus going?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on where you are in Oregon, one option is to choose a hardy hibiscus variety, *Hibiscus moscheuto*. These types of hibiscus tend to do better in cooler wintertime temperatures compared to the tropical varieties.
I would suggest planting a cutting from another plant in a larger pot (7" should do the trick) and try to find the sunniest spot possible in your small space. Water it whenever the soil feels dry. More details can be found here: 
https://homeguides.sfgate.com/care-hibiscus-zone-8-22869.html